# Как правильно передавать данные в класс?

Tags: php, yii2, ооп

Работаю на Yii2.
Есть модель. Пусть это будет анкета пользователя с множеством различных данных(User).
Есть класс, который в зависимости от данных этой анкеты и формирует, например, размер скидки для пользователя(пусть это будет класс FDiscount).
Вопрос в том как правильно сделать передачу данных в класс?

Я вижу два выхода:

1. Создаем метод в модели User, например, dataForFDiscount() в котором
   собираем массив данных, которые потребуются для работы FDiscount. И
   в дальнейшем передаем массив в конструктор класса FDiscount.
2. Передаем в FDiscount объект User и уже там разбираемся со всем
   сразу.

Меня тянет ко второму варианту. Сейчас все работает по первому.

Как будет правильно? Или может быть существует другое решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В DDD подходе используется паттерн DTO(Data Transfer Object), суть этого паттерна - создать типизированную структуру для передачи данных.

То есть вы создаете класс, к примеру `UserDTO` который принимает объект `User` и берёт только те данные которые вам нужны. И потом вы в своем классе `FDiscount` принимаете уже `UserDTO` в котором лежит то что вам нужно. Можете прочитать про этот паттерн и реализовать через него, а так если выбирать из вашего списка - я бы выбрал 2-й вариант.

Answer (score 0):

model, например \app\models\User:

```
public static function dataForFDiscount($user) {
    //что то делается с юзером проверяются наличие заполненности
    $discount = 0;

    if ($user->emailConfirm) {
       $discount += 5; 
    }

    return $discount;
}
```

controller, например \app\controllers\User (откуда вызываешь):

```
public function actionDiscount() {
   ....
   $discount = \app\models\User::dataForFDiscount(Yii::$app->user);
   ....
}
```

Как то так. Самый простой способ.

Comment: "Я бы не стал делать так" ... Способов куча. Этот самый простой. Почему user не должен знать об этом?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не стал делать так, чтобы User знал о FDiscount, а FDiscount о User.
Лучше передать в FDiscount просто параметры для формирования, например массив или объект простой.

Если у вас работает метод, в котором надо получить скидку, то в нем получаете User, формируете данные для FDiscount и отдаете в FDiscount.